# How do I put arguments into a drawable file (android studio)?

Tags: java, android, android-drawable, android-checkedtextview

I want to put all of these argument for this checkedtextview into a drawable file so that if I make more checkedtextviews I can use the same arguments the drawable file.

```
            <CheckedTextView
                android:id="@+id/DrinkWater"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                android:background="@drawable/startscreenbuttons"
                android:checked="true"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/checkbox"
                android:fontFamily="casual"
                android:onClick="do_drink_water"
                android:paddingLeft="3dp"
                android:paddingTop="3dp"
                android:text="@string/action_drink_water"
                android:textColor="#FFFF"
                android:textSize="20sp" />
```

Basically, how do I make CheckedTextView empty (except to call the drawable) and put it's arguments into this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

</selector>
```

Comment: You can use style instead of drawable for the same property to every checkbox.

Comment: How would I add all the properties to styles and call them in one line?

Comment: please wait,let me give you code.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html. You should go through basic android tutorials first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a style, e.g.

```
<style name="MyCheckedTextView" parent="@android:style/Widget.Material.CheckedTextView">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">35dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">2dp</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/startscreenbuttons</item>
    <item name="android:checked">true</item>
    <item name="android:drawableLeft">@drawable/checkbox</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">casual</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">3dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingTop">3dp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFF</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
</style>
```

and apply it to your view

```
<CheckedTextView
            android:id="@+id/DrinkWater"
            style="@style/MyCheckedTextView"
            //...
```

Also put your values in `dimens.xml` and `colors.xml`. It allows better layout management later in the project.

dimens.xml

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="dimen_name">5dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

colors.xml

```
<resources>
    <color name="color_name">#AABBCCDD</color> 
</resources>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!